# How to sort mutidimensional array by its key in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a mutidimensional array something like this

```
<?php 

$data2[3][1]=6;
$data2[9][3]=4;
$data2[9][2]=18;
$data2[4][2]=24;
$data2[4][0]=12;
$data2[4][1]=14;

?>
```

I want to sort this array by its key, so that it looks like this

```
$data2[3][1]=6;
$data2[4][0]=12;
$data2[4][1]=14;
$data2[4][2]=24;
$data2[9][2]=18;
$data2[9][3]=4;
```

used this

```
foreach ($data2 as $k[]){
ksort($k);

}

print_r($k);
```

but not working.

Comment: You're sorting the sub arrays. You just need the parent array sorted, so [ksort()](http://php.net/ksort) should do the trick. If you awnt the sub-arrays sorted too,t hen you'll need a custom function, which is what [usort()](http://php.net/usort) is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is necessary for the next level down

```
$data2[3][1]=6;
$data2[9][3]=4;
$data2[9][2]=18;
$data2[4][2]=24;
$data2[4][0]=12;
$data2[4][1]=14;

foreach($data2 as $key=>$data)
{
   ksort($data2[$key]);
}

ksort($data2);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data2);
echo '</pre>';
```

This will output

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => 6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 14
            [2] => 24
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [2] => 18
            [3] => 4
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to first sort the array, then the sub-arrays within.

```
ksort($data2); //Sort Array

foreach ($data2 as &$k){
    ksort($k); //Sort Each Sub-Array
}
```

**Updated based on Rocket Hazmat's comment**

Comment: `foreach ($data2 as $k){` needs to be `foreach ($data2 as &$k){` :-)

Comment: You are right, but would you care to explain? `$k` is passed as a normal array, no?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I am interested in this also.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal array"?  When you `foreach` you are operating on a copy of the array.  So when you `ksort($k)`, you are sorting it, but you are not updating the *original* array.  `&$k` makes `$k` a reference to the element in the original array.  Now when you update `$k`, it's updated in the original array.

Comment: @RocketHazmat is a genius. Nuff said.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thank you for the explanation. Running this code proves you're correct and my answer was updated. Makes sense. I would have used Humble Rat's `for` as opposed to `foreach` myself, but I was copying OP's code. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Docs for `foreach`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php :-D

Comment: Your explanation was perfect. I get it :)